# IFFT from FFT in AForge.Net

Tags: c#, fft, ifft

I'm rewriting code from Matlab to C#. I'm completely newb at mathematics. I had to use FFT function which I found in AForge.net library, but now I need IFFT. Is this possible to use FFT to compute IFFT in few lines?

Aforge.Net FFT declaration:

```
 public static void FFT (Complex[] data, Direction direction)
```

Comment: FFTW is too hard, because it is in C++. Also fttw wrapper for net doesnt work in new visual studio (cannot convert).

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  I found a wrapper for fftw that rocks, and I used it in my project.  I hope you have seen this: http://www.sdss.jhu.edu/~tamas/bytes/fftwcsharp.html

Comment: How to use it? I cannot load that solution into VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Inverse transform of an image, from [ComplexImage.cs](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/search?q=fft&origq=fft&btnG=Search%20Trunk).

```
         FourierTransform.FFT2( data, FourierTransform.Direction.Backward );
            fourierTransformed = false;

            for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ )
            {
                for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ )
                {
                    if ( ( ( x + y ) & 0x1 ) != 0 )
                    {
                        data[y, x].Re *= -1;
                        data[y, x].Im *= -1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: They are the same, except for the data variable that gets passed being one vs two dimensional. 

`public static void FFT2( Complex[,] data, Direction direction )`

`public static void FFT( Complex[] data, Direction direction )`

Comment: I just set FourierTransform.Direction to Forward and it works. Idk what your example is doing...

Comment: I don't follow. Just set the direction to Forward for FFT and Backward for IFFT - isn't that your question?